# How to remove black cursor in my inteljii Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, editor

I am having trouble.. I am unable to understand how to remove an black blinking space in my inteljii Idea. [Having an black space on line 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeIx7.png)

Comment: press `insert` button

Comment: Are you in `overwrite` mode?

Comment: Also check you do not have Tools | Vim Emulator mode enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You have possibly pressed the paste key (insert), usualy found above the arrow keys or near the page up/page down keys. Press the paste key once again

```
 FN + Return = Insert.   Or
```

.[image]

Comment: I have MacBook Air, what should i do? I have not any insert key.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: block cursor is set be default.

Uncheck `Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Use block caret` checkbox

Case 2: you are in `Overwrite` mode.

Assign shortcut to `Preferences -> Keymap -> Toggle Insert/Overwrite` action and press shortcut.